# Ошибка при сборке AOSP 8.0.0 под kenzo

Tags: android, build

```
[  0% 17/60340] //external/selinux/checkpolicy:checkpolicy yacc policy_parse.y [darwin]
FAILED: out/soong/.intermediates/external/selinux/checkpolicy/checkpolicy/darwin_x86_64/gen/yacc/external/selinux/checkpolicy/policy_parse.c out/soong/.intermediates/external/selinux/checkpolicy/checkpolicy/darwin_x86_64/gen/yacc/external/selinux/checkpolicy/policy_parse.h 
BISON_PKGDATADIR=external/bison/data prebuilts/misc/darwin-x86/bison/bison -d  --defines=out/soong/.intermediates/external/selinux/checkpolicy/checkpolicy/darwin_x86_64/gen/yacc/external/selinux/checkpolicy/policy_parse.h -o out/soong/.intermediates/external/selinux/checkpolicy/checkpolicy/darwin_x86_64/gen/yacc/external/selinux/checkpolicy/policy_parse.c external/selinux/checkpolicy/policy_parse.y
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
14:52:59 ninja failed with: exit status 1
make: *** [run_soong_ui] Error 1
```

Что означает эта ошибка? Используется macOS 10.13.